# Gitlab pipeline's default service account does not have permission to list services on kubernetes cluster

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have attached a kubernetes cluster with a Gitlab repo and installed a runner. When I try to list all the services in the same namespace, where pods are created, I get access deny error.

I need to either update the default service account or need to use a custom service account for the jobs who does the task. However, I am not able to find a way to do that.

The part of the code in .gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  environment:
    name: dev
  image: roffe/kubectl:v1.13.0
  script:
    - kubectl get svc -n $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

The error message:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-dev:my-dev-service-account" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "dev"
```

Please note that my-dev:my-dev-service-account is the default service account used by gitlab for this job. And also note that I have tried with KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE: ci-service-account option; however the job still uses the default service account. Could you please assist me here?

Answer (score 0):

By default gitlab-runner prevents you from overriding the service account using the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE` environment variable.

Did you pass `--kubernetes-service_account_overwrite_allowed=true` when registering the kubernetes runner? It could be what's missing here.

[See the documentation on Kubernetes runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html) for all parameters you can pass at registration time.

Comment: Thanks, @jphuynh. However, I have tried that too already as below.

Comment: 'deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  variables:
    KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED: .*
    KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE: ci-service-account '

Comment: Please note the value should be regular expression for 'KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED' as per the documentation

Comment: Unfortunately, the job still uses the default service and throw the same error again.

Comment: FYR:  $ kubectl get svc -n $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
 Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-dev:my-dev-service-account" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "dev"

Comment: Oh right my bad. I keep on misreading that flag :)

Did you create a kubernetes role for that service account allowing it to list the services in that `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` namespace?

Comment: The service is created by the CI by default. I am looking for a way to either use a custom service account or configure the job to use a different service account with required privileges. However, could not still find any option for either of those.